# What is this Alien Species in Futurama

Tags: futurama

In Futurama, the year 10,000 holds 5 Statues of Liberty from different species.  Humans, Birds, Monkeys, Cows, and an Alien blob sort of thing.  [image: http://theinfosphere.org/File:10000.png.]

What is that alien race?  Was the alien race ever shown in another other episode?

Answer (score 5):

If you listen to the dialogue, you'll hear Fry lamenting about how we've destroyed our own society. To make matters worse, so did the apes, birds, cows, and… "I don't know, is that a slug, maybe?" Those are the words Philip J. Fry uses when he sees their statue, but can't place what they are. I don't think the writers were actually trying to give a specific race, but rather thought that it would be funny to see Fry (and the audience) struggle in an attempt to identify the vague-looking statue of…something.

Comment: Fry said "No! They did it! They blew it up!  And then the apes blew up their society too. How could this happen?  And then the birds took over and ruined their society.  And then the cows. And then...  ... I don't know, is that a slug, maybe? Noooo!"  As for the race, the writers foreshadowed Nibbler's shadow in the very 1st episode.